# Following error encountered while using prediction class

Tags: python, api

While writing a simple code for prediction classes using imageai encountered the one problem

```py
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
prediction = ImagePrediction()

prediction.setModelTypeAsSqueezeNet()

prediction.setModelPath("squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")

prediction.loadModel(prediction_speed="normal")

prediction, probabilities = prediction.predictImage("image1.jpg", result_count=10)

print(rediction)
print(probabilities)
```

This is what i am getting

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "imageai.py", line 1, in <module>
        from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
      File "F:\python\iot\imageai.py", line 1, in <module>
        from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageai.Prediction'; 'imageai' is not a package
```

Comment: Can you try installing the package using this - `pip install --upgrade imageai`

Comment: Still facing the same error

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]